# Node & npm Error in mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

i am new on my mac I upgraded the node version and npm version. but after that its not working. It gives me error on all commands. please help me.
error is:

> zsh: command not found: node
>   zsh: command not found: phonegap

Comment: Make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I check it but bath $PATH is fine i.e /usr/local/bin

Comment: How did you install Node?

Comment: I put the command brew install node

Comment: I am getting stuck with brew in mac

Comment: I use Homebrew myself, but for Node I just use the [official installers](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Comment: its working thanks a lot .